# How to print date from jquery calender?

Tags: php, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have created a jquery calender as below

```
<div id="calendar"> </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#calendar').datepicker({
         inline: true,
         firstDay: 1,
         showOtherMonths: true,
         dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S']
    });
</script>
```

User can select date from this calender. Now how to print this date in php page using echo or other way? I want to store the date selected by user in database. how to do this?
link for jquery-ui-datepicker.min.js  is as follow: http://www.anmaveer.in/honda/js/jquery-ui-datepicker.min.js

Comment: I can't access the website provided in your link (http://www.anmaveer.in/)

Comment: I also can't acces the website

Answer (score 1):

create a text-box and set id of it "calendar"

```
<input type="text" name="calender_text" id="calendar">
```

Take this text box in a form and when submit this form, request this  filed

```
$_REQUEST['calender_text'];
```

and now you can insert this value in your Database

Comment: I tried this and this is working but issue is that the calender doesn't shown steady. It is shown only when the text box is clicked and after selecting the date the calender is disappeared, i want this calender to show every time. how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

First calendar will never show like this. Second if you need to get value, use a text field with id `calendar` then use your code :

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script>
$('#calendar').datepicker({
     inline: true,
     firstDay: 1,
     showOtherMonths: true,
     dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S']
});
 </script>
```

get the value of date selected on change event of date picker using `jQuery("#calendar").val();`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the date in JavaScript like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="calendar">
```

JS:

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S']
});

$('#calendar').on('change', function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
})
```

Everytime there is a new date selected, it will be logged to the console. You could easily change the `console.log()` to be your custom logic.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/6fJ9u/

Hope this helps

Comment: You don't ever use or need to use `</input>`

Comment: I tried this and this is working but issue is that the calender doesn't shown steady. It is shown only when the text box is clicked and after selecting the date the calender is disappeared, i want this calender to show every time. how to do this?

Comment: @Vallentin you are correct. Was tired when I did this and copy/pasted his `div` and renamed to input, hence the error. Edited to fix.

Answer (score 0):

u can use datepicker as class to any input with this code:

```
<input id="txt" class="datepicker" type="text" name="txt"></input>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
         inline: true,
         firstDay: 1,
         showOtherMonths: true,
         dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S']
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

[demo_update](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/6fJ9u/3/)

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
         inline: true,
         firstDay: 1,
         showOtherMonths: true,
         dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S']
    });
```

Comment: I tried this and this is working but issue is that the calender doesn't shown steady. It is shown only when the text box is clicked and after selecting the date the calender is disappeared, i want this calender to show every time. how to do this?